# Mongodb input in pentaho

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, kettle

I have a time field in mysql table. based on this time field I need to import data from mongodb collection.
So in Pentaho transformations first I have a Table Input step which gets the required date.
Next I have a mongodb input step.Here how do i filter records based on the output from previous step?

I saw that in mongodb input query it accepts parameters only if its an environment variable or defined in another transformation, but does not recognize variable from previous step.
How do I load from previous step, please help me I am a fresher in Pentaho and trying for this solution since a week.

Thank you,
Deepthi

Answer (score 1):

You've already answered your own question:

> I saw that in mongodb input query it accepts parameters only if its an environment variable or defined in another transformation, but does not recognize variable from previous step. How do I load from previous step, please help me I am a fresher in Pentaho and trying for this solution since a week.

If there is no way for a step to accept an input stream, you'll have to do exactly what you describe. In one transformation, access the MySQL table to get the time and store it in a variable. Then in another transformation access that variable in your MongoDB step.

Note that you will have to do this in two transformations to ensure that the variable is set by the time the MongoDB step runs.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was thinking is there any other way to load from previous step within same transformation.Because we have to load many tables and for each we have to create separate transformation just to have a variable.Is there any other way like a java plugin ? If there is no other solution then yes I will go ahead with separate transformation.

Comment: You can always build a custom Java step (either by creating a Java Step step or by writing a step plugin for Kettle) that does whatever you want, so that is a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at optiq.  This is bleeding edge, but allows sql access to mongodb, so in theory you could use it in a table input step rather than a mongo input step:

http://julianhyde.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/efficient-sql-queries-on-mongodb.html

Comment: Thank you that is really useful information.. But is it possible to join one table from mysql and the other from mongodb? Moreover we have Pentaho integration jobs to load data into staging tables.How to use it inside pentaho? Is it possible?

Comment: yes, just get your data from each source, make sure it's sorted on the join key and use the "join rows" step.  Not sure what you mean by the 2nd question.

Answer (score 0):

> It can be achieved  vai passing query as parameter.
>   In Transformation setting Add a parameter (eg : MONGO_QRY  )

Example

In MongoDB Query expression (json)

${MONGO_QRY}

It works fine for us try that . If not lets know .